# npm run build doesn't create a build folder for deployment

Tags: reactjs, vite

I started a React project with Vite. Created a simple notes app that works fine but when I want to deploy it using `npm run dev` or `npx vite build` there is no **build** folder. The output of these commands is succesful but couldn't find **build** folder for deployment.

```
✓ 74 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                   0.45 kB
dist/assets/index-a9bba2ed.css    3.06 kB │ gzip:  1.04 kB
dist/assets/index-757929e7.js   166.58 kB │ gzip: 54.39 kB
✓ built in 7.25s
```

Comment: Why did you expect a folder named build? Those lines clearly refer to dist.

Comment: If you want to set it to something else change the `outDir` in the config to `build`. https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-outdir

Comment: @jonrsharpe For integration with django. It doesn't have all the files.